# send parameter through before_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using a before action to execute an action called "can_accede" (this is in my aplication_controller) before accessing my index view, this action will look for a record to verify if the user can access my index view, but I need to send a parameter to that action to know what record to look for.

this is my "can_accede" action

```
def can_accede
  @can_accede = current_usuario.try(:perfiles).find_by_Descripcion(params[:Module_name]).try(:Listar)
  if @can_accede != true
    redirect_to root_path, alert: "you don't have permission."
  end
end
```

this is my before_action:

```
before_action :can_accede, only: [:index]
```

it is possible to send to the action can_accede through the before_action a `parameter param [: Module_name]`?

Comment: You have access to `controller_name` and `action_name` methods - are either of those what you're looking to pass into the params (or a combination), where you specify 'Module'?

Comment: The use of try in the can_accede method is not recommended, because if the current_usuario didn't get the required object through association or if it is nil, then it will through error as undefined method find_by_Descripcion for nil class. .

Answer (score 0):

The `params` object will be available in the method, so you can simply call `params[:whatever]` in `can_accede`.

FWIW, you should look into an authorization gem to unify your methods of authorization. [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) and [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) are good options.